# I want to crop a depth frame and get a cropped depth frame so that I can apply some methods on the cropped depth frame

Tags: python, realsense

Coding language: Python

I already went through the cropped depth frame using point cloud, but then I am unable to convert the cropped image back to the depth frame object.

Since my requirement is to crop the depth frame first using xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax then apply some predefined filter in **pyrealsense2**.

Comment: Question checklist: did you ask a question? Did you tag your question correctly? If it does not have code in it, are you absolutely sure it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

The description is a little bit unclear but, I am assuming you want to crop your depth frame by using xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax.
To do so you need to read the depth frame as a numpy array.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# reading the depth

depth_img = np.array(cv2.imread('depth.png', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))
height, width = depth_img.shape

depth = depth_img.astype(np.float32) * 0.001
depth.reshape(1, 1, height,width)
```

Now set the value of your choosing xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax.

```
xmin=100
xmax=149
ymin=122
ymax=196
```

Cropping the depth frame

```
cropped_depth = depth[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]

cv2.imshow("cropped depth",cropped_depth)
cv2.imwrite("cropped_depth.png",cropped_depth)
```

your frame will get cropped and be saved in the directory.